# 1&1 Windows hosting Server web.config URL rewrite issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-config

I am facing an issue related to URL rewrite in windows server hosted by 1&1. i am trying to rewrite the urls using web.config file but it's not working at all giving me the error or 500.19

Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x8007000d
Config Error
Config File \?\E:\kunden\homepages\0\d637982794\www\flight2day\web.config

Requested URL   https://flight2day.co.uk:443/
Physical Path
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
Failed Request Tracing Log Directory    faultRequestLogPath

here is the web.config code

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <authentication>
             <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
          </authentication>
       </security>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
          <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
        </modules>
        <rewrite>
              <rules>
                  <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^flight2day\.co.uk$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.flight2day.co.uk/{R:1}" />
                  </rule>
                  <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                  </rule>
                </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.aspx" />
                <add value="index.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="home.aspx" />
                <add value="home.asp" />
                <add value="home.htm" />
                <add value="home.html" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="default.asp" />
                <add value="default.htm" />
                <add value="default.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

here is .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +SymLinks
 AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to resolve this issue?