# How to fix 500.19 "faultRequestLogPath" failure?

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, redirect, iis-10

The code works on my local machine (IIS-7.5) but not online (on IIS-10)

**HTTP Error 500.19 - 0x8007000d - Internal Server Error - "faultRequestLogPath"**

"**system.webServer**" rule seems not to work somehow on online. I'm trying to redirect http to https (and i got it) but i can't get user friendly URLs.

High probably [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45887386/11-windows-hosting-server-web-config-url-rewrite-issues)...

```
<configuration>
  <location path="xXx.asp">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://example.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

**This "http to https redirection" code works...**

...

**but below code not...**

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rule 1">
        <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/404.asp" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="404.asp" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Rule 2">
      <match url="^(.*)| ?([_0-9a-z-]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="default.asp" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern=".css" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern=".js" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern=".png" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="xXx.asp?ulam={R:1}&amp;query={R}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  </rewrite>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
      <clear />
        <add value="index.asp" />
        <add value="home.asp" />
        <add value="default.asp" />
      </files>
  </defaultDocument>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/OaOInternal/DefaultWebs/sedoCurrent/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
  <handlers>
    <add name="IgnoreACCDB" verb="*" path="*.accdb" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
  </handlers>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
    <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".7z" mimeType="application/x-7z-compressed" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webmanifest" mimeType="application/manifest+json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

To get user friendly URLs i redirected all pages (requests) to one (**xXx**) page (except of some extensions) and i get the content from database with the help of querystring. But it won't work on IIS-10.

I know you have the solution, probably better one (a compact version of Rule1 and Rule2). Maybe you share it =))

Comment: That IIS 10 machine might not have URL Rewrite module installed. Install that and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosting firm finally replied. **system.webServer** is disabled. They told me to use **.htaccess** (and it works). Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look for windows feature and enable if not, the .NET Extensibility 3.5 under Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features >> Turn windows feature on or off